# Arduino and using a SSL secured mqtt broker

Tags: mqtt

I'm looking for a library helping me to connect from an Arduino to a MQTT Broker. Of course I want to secure the connection via TLS/SSL.

The "physical" connection is established via a **SIM800** module.
The Arduino itself should be as power efficient as possible (it's battery/solar powered).

In case the Arduino is too weak to perform such a task (SSL) is there any other suitable device? maybe a PyBoard?

Anyone can point me to the right direction?

Comment: I think an ESP8266 or an ARM based board running mbed-os would be the minimum requirement for such a product. Have you worked on one of these platforms already?

Comment: I used a esp8266 before, but i don't have wlan available at the location where this thing will be placed. thats why I need to use a sim800 module

Comment: You can switch off the WiFi radio of the ESP8266 and just use it as a cheap but fast 80MHz processor. But if you need real low power you should look in the STM32L1/4 series, e.g. a Nucleo L476RG board? That can drive the radio and a full TLS session with no problems.